# How works fault-proof in Optimistic rollups L2

Tags: rollups

I want to understand how works fault-proof concept in Optimistic rollups L2.

I have made tests on Optimism and Arbitrium's testnets.
It works fine but i want to know how i can revoke a transaction when there is a cheat.

How can i put a fake (cheat) transaction on Optimism (or Arbitrium) testnets ?
And how can i complain about this fake transaction after being approved on Layer 1 ?

Thanks

Comment: Best article about optimistic rollups: [(Almost) Everything you need to know about Optimistic Rollup](https://research.paradigm.xyz/rollups)